# Explicit description of the Galois group of $x^3+3x-2$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I am trying to find a Galois group of the polynomial $P(x) = x^3+3x-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. The roots of this polynomial can be written as
$$x_1 = \alpha, \quad x_2 = \frac{-\alpha+\beta}{2}, \quad \text{ and } \quad x_3 = \frac{-\alpha-\beta}{2},$$
where $\alpha$ denotes the only real root of $P(x)$ and $\beta = \sqrt{-3\alpha^2 - 12}$.  I found out that the splitting field of $P(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ should be $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$, which is of order $6$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Hence, all $6$ permutations of roots of $P(x)$ should give an automorphism, so the Galois group should be isomorphic to $S_3$.

So far, so well. However, I run into problems when I try to write the automorphisms of the Galois group explicitly. Since there are three possibilities for the image of $\alpha$ and two possibilities for the image of $\beta$, at least one of the automorphisms $\sigma$ should be given as $\sigma(\alpha) = (-\alpha+\beta)/2$ and $\sigma(\beta) = \beta$. However, when trying to compute $\sigma^2$, I get
$$\sigma^2(\alpha) = \sigma\left(\frac{-\alpha+\beta}{2}\right) = \frac{\alpha + \beta}{4},$$
which is not a root of $P(x)$ at all! So there has to be an error in my reasoning, but I have a hard time figuring it out. Could someone help?

Comment: How do you know that $-3\alpha^2-12$ is not a square in $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$ ? Your assumption that $\sigma(\beta)=\beta$ is wrong. If $\sigma$ doen't leave $-3\alpha^2-12$ fixed then it can't leave $\beta$ fixed.

Comment: Writing $\sigma(\beta)=\beta$ suggests you thought $\beta$ is a root of $P$, forgetting that's not what you defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should just let a permutation $\sigma$ act on $\Bbb Q(\alpha,\beta)$ by replacement $x_1\mapsto x_{\sigma(1)},x_2\mapsto x_{\sigma(2)},x_3\mapsto x_{\sigma(3)}$. Then, you deduce the action on $\alpha$ and $\beta$. For: $$\alpha=x_1$$Will be mapped to $x_{\sigma(1)}$, and: $$\beta=x_2-x_3$$Will be mapped to $x_{\sigma(2)}-x_{\sigma(3)}$.

Your proposed $\sigma$ takes $x_1$ to $x_2$ and takes $\beta$ to itself. Can this make sense? We know $x_2=-\frac{1}{2}x_1+\frac{1}{2}\beta$, so you suggest $\sigma(x_2)=-\frac{1}{2}\sigma(x_1)+\frac{1}{2}\sigma(\beta)=-\frac{1}{2}x_2+\frac{1}{2}\beta$, but this RHS is *not* a root. Your proposed automorphism has taken a root, $x_2$, to a non-root, and this can't be.

For example, let's say we take $x_1$ to $x_2$, and for fun let's take $x_2\mapsto x_1$ and $x_3\mapsto x_3$. Then this $\sigma$ would take $\alpha\mapsto x_2$ and $\beta$ to $\alpha-x_3$.

Comment: @AnneBauval ! That was an oversight